# Mezuzah on property that is being used for short term rentals

Tags: halacha

We have a house that is currently being used for short term rentals such as airbnb etc. Our guests are usually non Jews. Occasionally our family would also stay in the house for a weekend or a few days. Are we required to put mezuzahs?

P.S. we did put 1 on the main door

Thanks